# regex to match file names .txt and .cs (seperate calls) with only one "." in the file name

Tags: regex

I am attempting to write a regex to match every file name ending in `.txt` or `.cs` (separate calls) with no other `.` in their name.

Doing some research, I tried this.

For .cs

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.cs$
```

For .txt

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.txt$
```

But it does not seem to be returning with any matches.

.txt example:

Match `sometext.txt` but not `some.text.txt`

.cs example:

Match `somefile.cs` but not `some.file.txt`

Comment: But you are matching 2 dots? Are these examples part of a longer string?

Answer (score 1):

They aren't working as expected because they are trying to match exactly two periods (".") in the file names. To match file names that end with .txt or .cs without any other periods in their name, maybe try this pattern.

For .cs:

regex

```
^[^.]*\.cs$
```

For .txt:

regex

```
^[^.]*\.txt$
```

Here's what each pattern does:

^[^.]* matches any sequence of characters that does not contain a period. This ensures there are no other periods in the file name before the desired extension.

.cs$ or .txt$ ensures that the file name ends with the desired extension (.cs or .txt).

Here are examples of how these patterns work:

.cs Example:

Matches: somefile.cs

Does not match: some.file.cs

.txt Example:

Matches: sometext.txt

Does not match: some.text.txt

These patterns should give you the expected results for matching file names with the specified extensions and without any other periods in their names.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding the **regex** you're looking for is:

```
^[^.]*\.txt$
```

Replace .txt for .cs in the example above where it is required.

The previous example you had given was looking for:

1. Any character that's not a ".", 0 to unlimited times.
2. A explicit "." character.
3. Any character that's not a ".", 0 to unlimited times.
4. A explicit ".txt" or ".cs" ending.

There are amazing tools that can help you with regex.

Please find **[here](https://regex101.com/r/l7gkH6/1)** the regex I've recommended and **[here](https://regex101.com/r/KyolH5/1)** the regex you were using before.

Regex101 is a pretty good tool which explains every detail in regex and helps you testing and debugging your regular expressions.

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
^[^.]*\.(?:txt|cs)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^`** - Represents start of line
- **`$`** - Represents end of line
- **`[^.]*`** - Greedily matches every character other than `.`(and of course line breaks).
- **`\.`** - Matches `.` literal.
- **`(?:txt|cs)`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching either `txt` or `cs`. If you're looking for separate calls you can use it without capturing group something like `^[^.]*\.txt$` and `^[^.]*\.cs$`.

You can find the demo of the above regex in **[here.](https://regex101.com/r/gMcrNy/1)**
[image: regex_img]